# Change column name in Oracle in SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server, oracle, select

In MSSQL, I can select a column and change the column header by doing:

```
SELECT mycolumn as 'MyNewColumnName' from MyTable
```

This doesn't work in Oracle Database. How do I perform the same thing in Oracle Database?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

1. Remove single quotation marks

   ```
   SELECT mycolumn as MyNewColumnName 
     from MyTable
   ```
2. Enclose alias in double quotation marks

   ```
   SELECT mycolumn as "MyNewColumnName" 
     from MyTable
   ```

Comment: If you put double-quotes around it you'll make the name CaseSensitive, which means that everywhere you use it you'll have to enclose it in "Double Quotes" which gets old real fast.

Comment: And, you shouldn't use the single quotes in MS SQL either.  Use double quotes or square brackets.  Save the single quotes for string constants.

Comment: With the .Net Oracle client you'll end up with a DataTable with a column named MYNEWCOLUMNAME in case (1) and MyNewColumnName in case (2). So it is not only a matter of what Bob mentioned. This is especially important, if you hand over the raw results to a JSON formatter as it is done e.g. in WebAPI, because JS treats this differently.

Comment: In Toad for Oracle, this `SELECT mycolumn "MyNewColumnName" 
  from MyTable` and this `SELECT mycolumn MyNewColumnName 
  from MyTable` also work for me.

Comment: Have in mind, that this will change only how the column name will appear in the results. If you want to use this column in, let's say the WHERE clause, you need to refer to the column by it's original name and NOT bythe one you "renamed" it.
For example: `SELECT MyColumn as MyNewColumnName FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn='something'`.

Answer (score 8):

In Oracle you can just provide a space after the column name and provide the alias name without any quotes as

```
 SELECT mycolumn MyNewColumnName from MyTable
```

Comment: @Moudiz - please explain WHY you feel this is not good practice.

Comment: @Moudiz :-I am 100% sure the above thing will work...it not mandatory to use AS keyword. And this alias name can be used in code ahead also also. So I dont see any point of this not being a good practice.

Comment: @Harshit Why ignoring 'AS' if it exists ? someone told me (and I read it somewhere) that the alias AS is needed so the query will be more clearer exp: select my_col AS MYnewcool from my table will be clearer to the reader and why its bad practices because in other places 'AS' is obligatory exmpl: create table ex1 AS select * from msgs .If you remove AS here will cause syntanx error, so if you practice writing your queries without 'AS' it might -I am saying it might- You miss including AS somewhere in the script where you should

Comment: @Moudiz ok got your point. Just want to add that some places its mandatory to use As as you have cited and there are few more. If you dont use it there,  will get syntactical error. But in above answer using AS is worthless as I dont see any usability and good code practice.  PS:- no offenses :)

Comment: @Harshit it is matter of habbit, there are alot of places where you need to use alias, in join columns, procedures or many ways. I am thinking to post a question If 'AS' alias is a good habbit or not and we give the details that we mentioned and we will have different opinions .. what do you think ? after all we are here to share our knowlodge